# Shopify / Paypal Express: Shipping cost not showing until after payment

Tags: express, paypal, shopify

Ok so I got the following problem with my Shopify shop: Because my shipping varies based on weight paypal does not show the shipping rate until after the customer has logged in and paid for it. It then gets send back to Shopify where it receives the message that it will be billed an additional $10 for shipping, which already got me some complaints.

So what I want is that it will already shows the shipping cost before the customer logs in and pays for it. I imagined that more people had this problem and perhaps found a solution to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this with the PayPal system, but I'm not sure if Shopify is open enough for you to make any changes.  You'll probably need to ask them how it's configured and see if you have any option to adjust it.

The standard flow for Express Checkout is that you would show the user their cart and any fees you've gathered at that point so you can generate the subtotal.  Then you send them over to PayPal where they login and agree, and are then sent back to your site.  Back at your site you would obtain the shipping address from PayPal and you could then display a final review page that breaks down any additional shipping, tax, etc. that might be applied now that you know their shipping address.  No money would actually be charged until they approve this final review page.

In order to skip the additional review page on your own site, PayPal introduced the Instant Update API a few years ago.  This gives you the ability to generate a web service that PayPal's review page will call and send the shipping address so that the service can calculate shipping and tax and return it back to PayPal.  The PayPal review would then update accordingly so the buyer can choose their shipping option and see the grand total on the PayPal review page.  That way they can finalize and would still be returned to your site, but you wouldn't need to show another review.  You could simply show the thank you / receipt page.

I'm not sure if that first method I outlined is in fact what you're getting..??  It sounds like you're saying that Shopify is skipping the extra review, finalizing the payment, and then simply notifying the user that more money was charged than they agreed to.  If that's the case, I would say that's very sloppy checkout design.

Again, though, as Shopify is a hosted solution, you probably won't have the ability to adjust this on your own.  It's possible they have the Instant Update API available, though, and maybe you just need to enable it..??

You'll need to check with them for more details about your options.